# Changing polygon color with external link GeoJSON file

Tags: leaflet, geojson, style

I've tried various ways to change the polygon color with external links, but only one color can be displayed.

I need help with changing and displaying more than one polygon color in Leaflet, using an external GeoJSON file link.

Code:

```
fetch("https://testapp.my.id/batas_wilayah_sumbar.geojson")

    .then(function(response){
        return response.json();
    })
    .then(function(data1){
        
       L.geoJson(data1, {
        style:function(feature){
         return{
            
                style:myStyle
           
        },
          onEachFeature:onEachFeature
       })
    .addTo(myMap);
    });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no difference between external or local file. While you are creating `.geojson` layer using leaflet, you can set style for each feature:

```js
var map = L.map('mapContainer', {
   center: [0,0],
   zoom: 10,
})

var vectorLayer = L.geoJSON("data.geojson", {
    style: function(feature) {
        switch (feature.properties.class) {
            case '1': return style1;
            case '2': return style2;
            ...
        }
    }
}).addTo(map);
```

You need to have a property (in this example it is "class") which enables us to classify polygons.