# Plotting on map Leaflet when I GeoJSON that comes polygon and mutipolygon (in the same JSON)

Tags: leaflet, geojson, mapping, react

I have a GeoJSON that comes with polygon and multipolygon geometry types. Can I plot it on the map anyway, or would it have to be different APIs? And if possible, how would I manage to do that?

I have a lot of with `"type": "MultiPolygon"`, e `"type": "Polygon"`

Code plot

```js
   if (map) {
      L.tileLayer(
        'https://services.arcgisonline.com/arcgis/rest/services/Ocean/World_Ocean_Base/MapServer/tile/{z}/{y}/{x}.png',
        {
          id: 'equinor/psa/data-inventory',
        }
      ).addTo(map);

      var geojsonPolygon = L.geoJSON(polygon, {
        style: function (feature) {
          return {
            stroke: true,
            fillColor: feature.color,
            fillOpacity: feature.opacity,
            color: feature.color,
            opacity: feature.opacity,
            weight: 2,
          };
        },
        smoothFactor: 6,
      })
```

JSON example

```json
[
{
    "codBloco": "ALTO_CF_CE",
    "codFaseC": "E",
    "datAssina": null,
    "datTermin": null,
    "nomBacia": "Campos",
    "nomBloco": "ALTO_CF_CE",
    "nomFantas": "ALTO DE CABO FRIO CENTRAL",
    "numContra": 48610012962201714,
    "numDescob": 0,
    "operadorC": "Petr?leo Brasileiro S.A. - PETROBRAS",
    "rodada": "Partilha 3",
    "areaTotal": 3674.3687069,
    "ambiente": "M",
    "blocos": "ALTO DE CABO FRIO CENTRAL",
    "codSaof": 1,
    "geometry": "POLYGON ((-40.6770833333333 -23.8567708333333, -40.6770833333333 -23.9375, -40.7213541666667 -23.9375, -40.7213541666667 -23.9609375, -40.7473958333333 -23.9609375, -40.7473958333333 -24.1197916666667, -40.7916666666667 -24.1197916666667, -40.7916666666667 -24.1432291666667, -40.8229166666667 -24.1432291666667, -40.8229166666667 -24.1640625, -40.8854166666667 -24.1640625, -40.8854166666667 -24.2213541666667, -40.9401041666667 -24.2213541666667, -40.9401041666667 -24.40625, -41.0546875 -24.40625, -41.0546875 -24.4375, -41.0651041666667 -24.4375, -41.0651041666667 -24.4557291666667, -41.1015625 -24.4557291666667, -41.1015625 -24.4635416666667, -41.1484375 -24.4635416666667, -41.1484375 -24.4921875, -41.1770833333333 -24.4921875, -41.1770833333333 -24.5026041666667, -41.2473958333333 -24.5026041666667, -41.2473958333333 -24.5442708333333, -41.3828125 -24.5442708333333, -41.3828125 -24.4348958333333, -41.3333333333333 -24.4348958333333, -41.3333333333333 -24.2447916666667, -41.4010416666667 -24.2447916666667, -41.4010416666667 -24.21875, -41.4609375 -24.21875, -41.4609375 -24.0885416666667, -41.4947916666667 -24.0885416666667, -41.4947916666667 -23.9375, -41.15625 -23.9375, -41.15625 -23.8958333333333, -41.0286458333333 -23.8958333333333, -41.0286458333333 -23.9192708333333, -40.8932291666667 -23.9192708333333, -40.8932291666667 -23.890625, -40.8333333333333 -23.890625, -40.8333333333333 -23.8567708333333, -40.6770833333333 -23.8567708333333))",
    "geoJson": {
      "id": "15",
      "type": "Feature",
      "properties": {},
      "geometry": {
        "type": "Polygon",
        "coordinates": [
          [
            [
              -40.6770833333333,
              -23.8567708333333
            ],
            [
              -40.6770833333333,
              -23.9375
            ],
            [
              -40.7213541666667,
              -23.9375
            ],
            [
              -40.7213541666667,
              -23.9609375
            ],
            [
              -40.7473958333333,
              -23.9609375
            ],
            [
              -40.7473958333333,
              -24.1197916666667
            ],
            [
              -40.7916666666667,
              -24.1197916666667
            ],
            [
              -40.7916666666667,
              -24.1432291666667
            ],
            [
              -40.8229166666667,
              -24.1432291666667
            ],
            [
              -40.8229166666667,
              -24.1640625
            ],
            [
              -40.8854166666667,
              -24.1640625
            ],
            [
              -40.8854166666667,
              -24.2213541666667
            ],
            [
              -40.9401041666667,
              -24.2213541666667
            ],
            [
              -40.9401041666667,
              -24.40625
            ],
            [
              -41.0546875,
              -24.40625
            ],
            [
              -41.0546875,
              -24.4375
            ],
            [
              -41.0651041666667,
              -24.4375
            ],
            [
              -41.0651041666667,
              -24.4557291666667
            ],
            [
              -41.1015625,
              -24.4557291666667
            ],
            [
              -41.1015625,
              -24.4635416666667
            ],
            [
              -41.1484375,
              -24.4635416666667
            ],
            [
              -41.1484375,
              -24.4921875
            ],
            [
              -41.1770833333333,
              -24.4921875
            ],
            [
              -41.1770833333333,
              -24.5026041666667
            ],
            [
              -41.2473958333333,
              -24.5026041666667
            ],
            [
              -41.2473958333333,
              -24.5442708333333
            ],
            [
              -41.3828125,
              -24.5442708333333
            ],
            [
              -41.3828125,
              -24.4348958333333
            ],
            [
              -41.3333333333333,
              -24.4348958333333
            ],
            [
              -41.3333333333333,
              -24.2447916666667
            ],
            [
              -41.4010416666667,
              -24.2447916666667
            ],
            [
              -41.4010416666667,
              -24.21875
            ],
            [
              -41.4609375,
              -24.21875
            ],
            [
              -41.4609375,
              -24.0885416666667
            ],
            [
              -41.4947916666667,
              -24.0885416666667
            ],
            [
              -41.4947916666667,
              -23.9375
            ],
            [
              -41.15625,
              -23.9375
            ],
            [
              -41.15625,
              -23.8958333333333
            ],
            [
              -41.0286458333333,
              -23.8958333333333
            ],
            [
              -41.0286458333333,
              -23.9192708333333
            ],
            [
              -40.8932291666667,
              -23.9192708333333
            ],
            [
              -40.8932291666667,
              -23.890625
            ],
            [
              -40.8333333333333,
              -23.890625
            ],
            [
              -40.8333333333333,
              -23.8567708333333
            ],
            [
              -40.6770833333333,
              -23.8567708333333
            ]
          ]
        ]
      },
      "bbox": [
        -41.4947916666667,
        -24.5442708333333,
        -40.6770833333333,
        -23.8567708333333
      ]
    },
    "basinName": "Espirito Santo",
    "blockGuid": null,
    "basinGuid": 1003519151
  },
    "codBloco": "C-M-101",
    "codFaseC": "E",
    "datAssina": "24-11-2004",
    "datTermin": null,
    "nomBacia": "Campos",
    "nomBloco": "C-M-101",
    "nomFantas": "BM-C-30",
    "numContra": 486100079742004,
    "numDescob": 7,
    "operadorC": "BP Energy do Brasil Ltda.",
    "rodada": "Rodada 6",
    "areaTotal": 340.0,
    "ambiente": null,
    "blocos": "C-M-101",
    "codSaof": 5343,
    "geometry": "MULTIPOLYGON (((-39.7838541666667 -21.625, -39.7760416666667 -21.625, -39.7760416666667 -21.6354166666667, -39.7682291666667 -21.6354166666667, -39.7682291666667 -21.6848958333333, -39.7578125 -21.6848958333333, -39.7578125 -21.71875, -39.7503874113639 -21.71875, -39.7503874183378 -21.7213541666667, -39.7503874253127 -21.7239583333333, -39.7503874322887 -21.7265625, -39.7503874392658 -21.7291666666667, -39.7503874462439 -21.7317708333333, -39.7503874532231 -21.734375, -39.7503874602033 -21.7369791666667, -39.7503874671845 -21.7395833333333, -39.7503874741668 -21.7421875, -39.7916666666667 -21.7421875, -39.7916666666667 -21.7239583333333, -39.8020833333333 -21.7239583333333, -39.8020833333333 -21.7005208333333, -39.8072916666667 -21.7005208333333, -39.8072916666667 -21.6588541666667, -39.8255208333333 -21.6588541666667, -39.8255208333333 -21.640625, -39.8333333333333 -21.640625, -39.8333333333333 -21.625, -39.859375 -21.625, -39.859375 -21.6666666666667, -39.875 -21.6666666666667, -39.875 -21.6744791666667, -39.8854166666667 -21.6744791666667, -39.8854166666667 -21.734375, -39.9739583333333 -21.734375, -39.9739583333333 -21.6510416666667, -39.9583333333333 -21.6510416666667, -39.9583333333333 -21.640625, -39.9348958333333 -21.640625, -39.9348958333333 -21.6171875, -39.9088541666667 -21.6171875, -39.9088541666667 -21.6015625, -39.9010416666667 -21.6015625, -39.9010416666667 -21.5572916666667, -39.8515625 -21.5572916666667, -39.8515625 -21.5677083333333, -39.8333333333333 -21.5677083333333, -39.8333333333333 -21.5520833333333, -39.7838541666667 -21.5520833333333, -39.7838541666667 -21.625)), ((-40.0003891105328 -21.5004965409529, -39.9977849201413 -21.5004965470188, -39.995180729749 -21.5004965530844, -39.9925765393559 -21.5004965591496, -39.989972348962 -21.5004965652144, -39.9873681585673 -21.5004965712788, -39.9847639681718 -21.5004965773429, -39.9821597777755 -21.5004965834067, -39.9795555873784 -21.50049658947, -39.9769513969805 -21.500496595533, -39.9743472065817 -21.5004966015956, -39.9717430161822 -21.5004966076578, -39.9691388257819 -21.5004966137197, -39.9665346353808 -21.5004966197812, -39.9639304449788 -21.5004966258423, -39.9613262545761 -21.500496631903, -39.9587220641725 -21.5004966379634, -39.9561178737682 -21.5004966440234, -39.953513683363 -21.5004966500831, -39.9509094929571 -21.5004966561424, -39.9483053025503 -21.5004966622013, -39.9457011121428 -21.5004966682598, -39.9430969217344 -21.500496674318, -39.9404927313253 -21.5004966803758, -39.9378885409153 -21.5004966864332, -39.9352843505045 -21.5004966924902, -39.9326801600929 -21.5004966985469, -39.9300759696806 -21.5004967046032, -39.9274717792674 -21.5004967106592, -39.9248675888534 -21.5004967167147, -39.9222633984387 -21.5004967227699, -39.9196592080231 -21.5004967288248, -39.9170550176067 -21.5004967348792, -39.9144508271895 -21.5004967409333, -39.9118466367715 -21.5004967469871, -39.9092424463527 -21.5004967530404, -39.9066382559331 -21.5004967590934, -39.9040340655127 -21.500496765146, -39.9010416666667 -21.5004967711982, -39.9010416666667 -21.5182291666667, -39.9192708333333 -21.5182291666667, -39.9192708333333 -21.5338541666667, -39.9348958333333 -21.5338541666667, -39.9348958333333 -21.5520833333333, -39.9505208333333 -21.5520833333333, -39.9505208333333 -21.5677083333333, -39.96875 -21.5677083333333, -39.96875 -21.5859375, -40.000389339668 -21.5859375, -40.0003893327078 -21.5833333333333, -40.0003893257485 -21.5807291666667, -40.0003893187903 -21.578125, -40.0003893118332 -21.5755208333333, -40.0003893048771 -21.5729166666667, -40.0003892979221 -21.5703125, -40.0003892909681 -21.5677083333333, -40.0003892840152 -21.5651041666667, -40.0003892770633 -21.5625, -40.0003892701124 -21.5598958333333, -40.0003892631627 -21.5572916666667, -40.0003892562139 -21.5546875, -40.0003892492662 -21.5520833333333, -40.0003892423196 -21.5494791666667, -40.000389235374 -21.546875, -40.0003892284295 -21.5442708333333, -40.000389221486 -21.5416666666667, -40.0003892145435 -21.5390625, -40.0003892076021 -21.5364583333333, -40.0003892006618 -21.5338541666667, -40.0003891937225 -21.53125, -40.0003891867843 -21.5286458333333, -40.0003891798471 -21.5260416666667, -40.0003891729109 -21.5234375, -40.0003891659758 -21.5208333333333, -40.0003891590418 -21.5182291666667, -40.0003891521088 -21.515625, -40.0003891451768 -21.5130208333333, -40.0003891382459 -21.5104166666667, -40.0003891313161 -21.5078125, -40.0003891243873 -21.5052083333333, -40.0003891174595 -21.5026041666667, -40.0003891105328 -21.5004965409529)))",
    "geoJson": {
      "id": "50",
      "type": "Feature",
      "properties": {},
      "geometry": {
        "type": "MultiPolygon",
        "coordinates": [
          [
            [
              [
                -39.7838541666667,
                -21.625
              ],
              [
                -39.7760416666667,
                -21.625
              ],
              [
                -39.7760416666667,
                -21.6354166666667
              ],
              [
                -39.7682291666667,
                -21.6354166666667
              ],
              [
                -39.7682291666667,
                -21.6848958333333
              ],
              [
                -39.7578125,
                -21.6848958333333
              ],
              [
                -39.7578125,
                -21.71875
              ],
              [
                -39.7503874113639,
                -21.71875
              ],
              [
                -39.7503874183378,
                -21.7213541666667
              ],
              [
                -39.7503874253127,
                -21.7239583333333
              ],
              [
                -39.7503874322887,
                -21.7265625
              ],
              [
                -39.7503874392658,
                -21.7291666666667
              ],
              [
                -39.7503874462439,
                -21.7317708333333
              ],
              [
                -39.7503874532231,
                -21.734375
              ],
              [
                -39.7503874602033,
                -21.7369791666667
              ],
              [
                -39.7503874671845,
                -21.7395833333333
              ],
              [
                -39.7503874741668,
                -21.7421875
              ],
              [
                -39.7916666666667,
                -21.7421875
              ],
              [
                -39.7916666666667,
                -21.7239583333333
              ],
              [
                -39.8020833333333,
                -21.7239583333333
              ],
              [
                -39.8020833333333,
                -21.7005208333333
              ],
              [
                -39.8072916666667,
                -21.7005208333333
              ],
              [
                -39.8072916666667,
                -21.6588541666667
              ],
              [
                -39.8255208333333,
                -21.6588541666667
              ],
              [
                -39.8255208333333,
                -21.640625
              ],
              [
                -39.8333333333333,
                -21.640625
              ],
              [
                -39.8333333333333,
                -21.625
              ],
              [
                -39.859375,
                -21.625
              ],
              [
                -39.859375,
                -21.6666666666667
              ],
              [
                -39.875,
                -21.6666666666667
              ],
              [
                -39.875,
                -21.6744791666667
              ],
              [
                -39.8854166666667,
                -21.6744791666667
              ],
              [
                -39.8854166666667,
                -21.734375
              ],
              [
                -39.9739583333333,
                -21.734375
              ],
              [
                -39.9739583333333,
                -21.6510416666667
              ],
              [
                -39.9583333333333,
                -21.6510416666667
              ],
              [
                -39.9583333333333,
                -21.640625
              ],
              [
                -39.9348958333333,
                -21.640625
              ],
              [
                -39.9348958333333,
                -21.6171875
              ],
              [
                -39.9088541666667,
                -21.6171875
              ],
              [
                -39.9088541666667,
                -21.6015625
              ],
              [
                -39.9010416666667,
                -21.6015625
              ],
              [
                -39.9010416666667,
                -21.5572916666667
              ],
              [
                -39.8515625,
                -21.5572916666667
              ],
              [
                -39.8515625,
                -21.5677083333333
              ],
              [
                -39.8333333333333,
                -21.5677083333333
              ],
              [
                -39.8333333333333,
                -21.5520833333333
              ],
              [
                -39.7838541666667,
                -21.5520833333333
              ],
              [
                -39.7838541666667,
                -21.625
              ]
            ]
          ],
          [
            [
              [
                -40.0003891105328,
                -21.5004965409529
              ],
              [
                -39.9977849201413,
                -21.5004965470188
              ],
              [
                -39.995180729749,
                -21.5004965530844
              ],
              [
                -39.9925765393559,
                -21.5004965591496
              ],
              [
                -39.989972348962,
                -21.5004965652144
              ],
              [
                -39.9873681585673,
                -21.5004965712788
              ],
              [
                -39.9847639681718,
                -21.5004965773429
              ],
              [
                -39.9821597777755,
                -21.5004965834067
              ],
              [
                -39.9795555873784,
                -21.50049658947
              ],
              [
                -39.9769513969805,
                -21.500496595533
              ],
              [
                -39.9743472065817,
                -21.5004966015956
              ],
              [
                -39.9717430161822,
                -21.5004966076578
              ],
              [
                -39.9691388257819,
                -21.5004966137197
              ],
              [
                -39.9665346353808,
                -21.5004966197812
              ],
              [
                -39.9639304449788,
                -21.5004966258423
              ],
              [
                -39.9613262545761,
                -21.500496631903
              ],
              [
                -39.9587220641725,
                -21.5004966379634
              ],
              [
                -39.9561178737682,
                -21.5004966440234
              ],
              [
                -39.953513683363,
                -21.5004966500831
              ],
              [
                -39.9509094929571,
                -21.5004966561424
              ],
              [
                -39.9483053025503,
                -21.5004966622013
              ],
              [
                -39.9457011121428,
                -21.5004966682598
              ],
              [
                -39.9430969217344,
                -21.500496674318
              ],
              [
                -39.9404927313253,
                -21.5004966803758
              ],
              [
                -39.9378885409153,
                -21.5004966864332
              ],
              [
                -39.9352843505045,
                -21.5004966924902
              ],
              [
                -39.9326801600929,
                -21.5004966985469
              ],
              [
                -39.9300759696806,
                -21.5004967046032
              ],
              [
                -39.9274717792674,
                -21.5004967106592
              ],
              [
                -39.9248675888534,
                -21.5004967167147
              ],
              [
                -39.9222633984387,
                -21.5004967227699
              ],
              [
                -39.9196592080231,
                -21.5004967288248
              ],
              [
                -39.9170550176067,
                -21.5004967348792
              ],
              [
                -39.9144508271895,
                -21.5004967409333
              ],
              [
                -39.9118466367715,
                -21.5004967469871
              ],
              [
                -39.9092424463527,
                -21.5004967530404
              ],
              [
                -39.9066382559331,
                -21.5004967590934
              ],
              [
                -39.9040340655127,
                -21.500496765146
              ],
              [
                -39.9010416666667,
                -21.5004967711982
              ],
              [
                -39.9010416666667,
                -21.5182291666667
              ],
              [
                -39.9192708333333,
                -21.5182291666667
              ],
              [
                -39.9192708333333,
                -21.5338541666667
              ],
              [
                -39.9348958333333,
                -21.5338541666667
              ],
              [
                -39.9348958333333,
                -21.5520833333333
              ],
              [
                -39.9505208333333,
                -21.5520833333333
              ],
              [
                -39.9505208333333,
                -21.5677083333333
              ],
              [
                -39.96875,
                -21.5677083333333
              ],
              [
                -39.96875,
                -21.5859375
              ],
              [
                -40.000389339668,
                -21.5859375
              ],
              [
                -40.0003893327078,
                -21.5833333333333
              ],
              [
                -40.0003893257485,
                -21.5807291666667
              ],
              [
                -40.0003893187903,
                -21.578125
              ],
              [
                -40.0003893118332,
                -21.5755208333333
              ],
              [
                -40.0003893048771,
                -21.5729166666667
              ],
              [
                -40.0003892979221,
                -21.5703125
              ],
              [
                -40.0003892909681,
                -21.5677083333333
              ],
              [
                -40.0003892840152,
                -21.5651041666667
              ],
              [
                -40.0003892770633,
                -21.5625
              ],
              [
                -40.0003892701124,
                -21.5598958333333
              ],
              [
                -40.0003892631627,
                -21.5572916666667
              ],
              [
                -40.0003892562139,
                -21.5546875
              ],
              [
                -40.0003892492662,
                -21.5520833333333
              ],
              [
                -40.0003892423196,
                -21.5494791666667
              ],
              [
                -40.000389235374,
                -21.546875
              ],
              [
                -40.0003892284295,
                -21.5442708333333
              ],
              [
                -40.000389221486,
                -21.5416666666667
              ],
              [
                -40.0003892145435,
                -21.5390625
              ],
              [
                -40.0003892076021,
                -21.5364583333333
              ],
              [
                -40.0003892006618,
                -21.5338541666667
              ],
              [
                -40.0003891937225,
                -21.53125
              ],
              [
                -40.0003891867843,
                -21.5286458333333
              ],
              [
                -40.0003891798471,
                -21.5260416666667
              ],
              [
                -40.0003891729109,
                -21.5234375
              ],
              [
                -40.0003891659758,
                -21.5208333333333
              ],
              [
                -40.0003891590418,
                -21.5182291666667
              ],
              [
                -40.0003891521088,
                -21.515625
              ],
              [
                -40.0003891451768,
                -21.5130208333333
              ],
              [
                -40.0003891382459,
                -21.5104166666667
              ],
              [
                -40.0003891313161,
                -21.5078125
              ],
              [
                -40.0003891243873,
                -21.5052083333333
              ],
              [
                -40.0003891174595,
                -21.5026041666667
              ],
              [
                -40.0003891105328,
                -21.5004965409529
              ]
            ]
          ]
        ]
      },
      "bbox": [
        -40.000389339668,
        -21.7421875,
        -39.7503874113639,
        -21.5004965409529
      ]
    },
    "basinName": "Campos",
    "blockGuid": 1007220583,
    "basinGuid": 1003519264
  },
  
  ]
```

Comment: That looks like malformed JSON near `}, "codBloco": "C-M-101",`. Other than that, `L.geoJSON(json[0].geoJson)` should get you on the right track.

Comment: A geojson which supports `FeatureCollection` type is a cure.

Comment: Please don't re-ask questions that you've already had closed.  Rather you should edit your original question to improve so that it can be re-opened.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, I would say `.geojson` instead of `.json` as the first format contains both coordinate data and attributes which can be shown on map.

Each `.geojson` file supports a specific type of geometry say `point`, `line`, `polygon` and so on. A complete valid list of geometry types [is here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GeoJSON).

A complex type of `.geojson` file that can handle different geometry types at the same time is called `FeatureCollection` in which you can store multiple geometry type and display it as a overlay layer on basemap. This is what you need:

```json
{
  "type": "FeatureCollection",
  "features": [
    {
      "type": "Feature",
      "geometry": {
        "type": "Point",
        "coordinates": [...]
      },
      "properties": {...}
    },
    ...,
    {
      "type": "Feature",
      "geometry": {
        "type": "Polygon",
        "coordinates": [...]
      },
      "properties": {...}
    }
  ]
}
```

So in your case, you can store `Polygon` and `MultiPolygon` in one object. However, I couldn't use the `.geojson` object you have shared in the question and I think it is invalid. There is an [Online Tool](https://geojson.io/#map=8/0.500/102.500) through which you are able to validate and view your `geojson` object on map.

If the `.geojson` object you are using follows mentioned structure, the **geojson** layer is created and styled as follow:

```js
const pointStyle = {...}
const lineStyle = {...}
...
L.geoJSON(geojson_object, {
    style: function (feature) {
        switch (feature.geometry.type) {
            case 'Point': return pointStyle,
            case 'LineString': return lineStyle,
            case 'Polygon': return polygonStyle
        }
    }
}).addTo(map)
```

You can also apply style on features based on their properties. I described it [here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/382400/changing-polygon-color-with-external-link-geojson-file/382407#382407).